# Building JS dependencies into html file

Tags: html, node.js, webpack, web-deployment

I have built a 403-Page using company internal webcomponents and an internal framework. The problem is that the auth-layer of our framwork, in case of missing authorization, allows access to only ONE single file: the 403.html.

Putting all the CSS and JS scripts into my html file is no problem. However, my problem are the dependencies I have from the webcomponents. I am loading them with a

```
<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
```

where the index.js consists of only import statements. And I use snowpack to build my 403 app, which builds the dependencies in an extra folder. Since out framwork does not allow access to any other files except the 403.html, I am wondering if there is a build tool that can bundle all the dependencies and inject them into my html file?

Comment: Can't "snowpack" bundle?

Comment: Snowpack is lightweight and as far as I understand only supports bundling through a webpack plugin. All the examples I see about webpack only bundled the css and js but I could not figure out what happens to the dependencies

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is a top Google search result for `snowpack single-file bundle`... if snowpack makes this _possible_, it certainly doesn't make it clear how to actually _do_ it...